# Nth list entry as id

Tags: r

Sample data:

```
  l <- list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, data.frame(x=1,z=5))
```

I have tried among others:

```
 lapply(1:length(l), function(i) l$id <- i)
```

Desired result:

```
l
[[1]]
 NULL

[[2]]
 NULL

[[3]]
 NULL

[[4]]
 NULL

[[5]]
  id x z 
1  5 1 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We loop through the sequence of 'l', `if` the `list` element is `NULL` we return `NULL` or else `cbind` with the corresponding sequence.

```
 lapply(seq_along(l), function(i) if(is.null(l[[i]])) NULL
                           else cbind(l[[i]], i))
```

Or we can get the index of `NULL` elements and cbind only the subset of non-null elements with corresponding 'id'

```
 ind <- !sapply(l, is.null)
 l[ind] <- Map(cbind, l[ind], id=seq_along(l)[ind])
```

Comment: You are too fast my friend

Comment: @RichardScriven I was thinking about the index method earlier, but I posted the `lapply` as the OP was using it.